# SQL, buscar apenas um elemento por categoria

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Estou a tentar fazer uma query SQL que selecione apenas um elemento por cat_id, do genero de um ciclo For onde verifica se já existe um cat_id=1 e se já tiver passa para a frente até correr a tabela toda.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

estou a utilizar esta função para ir buscar todos os ficheiros

```
public function get_products()
    {
        $sql  = "SELECT * FROM products";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql); 
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

e quero apenas ir buscar 1 por cat_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se eu entendi corretamente, você quer retornar suas categorias e apenas 1 registro de cada. Isso você pode conseguir fazendo uma query base que retorne o último ID registrado para uma categoria

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM products GROUP BY cat_id
```

Caso a sua necessidade seja retornar o primeiro produto por categoria, basta alterar o MAX por MIN.

Com base nesta query, você pode retornar as informações desta forma:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE id in (SELECT MAX(id) FROM products GROUP BY cat_id)
```

Comment: obrigado, era exatamente isso